# Can OR-clauses be combined with distance filters in Haystack for Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-haystack, searchqueryset

I've been using a distance filter using regular django query filters within an OR-clause:

```
# either it's within the preset distance of the location
# OR it's not an in-person event
self.filter(Q(location__distance_lt=(geometry, LOCATION_WITHIN_D)) | ~Q(type=Event.IN_PERSON))
```

I want to do a similar filtering as part of a haystack query, using SQ:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(SQ(location__distance_lt=(geometry, LOCATION_WITHIN_D)) | ~SQ(type=Event.IN_PERSON))
```

but instead I get back the error: `not all arguments converted during string formatting` - and that only happens with the distance_lt query part, not the `~SQ(type..)`

I'm able to apply the distance filtering with my haystack search query by using

```
queryset = queryset.dwithin('location', geometry, LOCATION_WITHIN_D)`
```

but I want to be able to have that 'or' condition in this sub-clause.

Is this even possible with raw querying? How can I construct such a raw query for ElasticSearch and still execute it as part of my haystack query?

Comment: For context, you're using [`django.contrib.gis`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/) (GeoDjango) and [django-haystack](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/)'s [SpatialSearch](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spatial.html)?

Comment: @TonyN - this is using the SpatialSearch business for haystack, and the gis stuff for our regular DB lookups

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the search against the Elasticsearch connection.

```py
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

sqs = SearchQuerySet('default')
be = sqs.query.backend
LOCATION_WITHIN_D = D(km=0.1)
geometry = {
    "lat": 60.1939,
    "lon": 11.1003
}

raw_query = {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "type": Event.IN_PERSON
                }
              },
              {
                "geo_distance": {
                  "distance": str(LOCATION_WITHIN_D),
                  "location": geometry
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
result = be.conn.search(body=raw_query, index='name-of-your-index')
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still applies the location filtering in an "AND" way when the query is evaluated. It's a useful thing to know that you can combine querysets with an OR like that similar to combining SQs inside a filter clause, so thanks for that.

Comment: I wrote a way to do a raw query against the Elastic search connection

Comment: Thanks again for following up on this. Are the various fields within the 'should' clause evaluated separately in an "OR" way or are they being combined as an AND? I guess I'll need to study more about the raw queries since I would like to keep a lot of the 'easy' bits from the django querying tool but include this particular filter as an additional, handwritten part if I have to.

Comment: The should clause gets [evaluated in an OR way](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/query-dsl-bool-query.html). At least one of the should queries should match for a document to be returned in the result.